# Free quad polarization SAR images of San Francisco in bands X and L?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, city, research

For comparing the results in my scientific article I need quad polarized sample data for San Francisco in bands **C(RADARSAT-2)**, **L(probably ALOS-PALSAR)** and **X(probably TerraSAR-X)**
[image]
Up to now I have downloaded band C of this data from [GEOSPATIAL SERVICES INTERNATIONAL](http://gs.mdacorporation.com/SatelliteData/Radarsat2/SampleDataset.aspx) but I don't know where can I download the X and L bands of the same area?